# View resize when In-Call Status Bar changes

Tags: ios, resize, interface-builder, xib

I'm trying to understand what the expectation is around view resizing.

I've currently got my iOS app working with dynamic view sizes. That is, they are laid out correctly both when the In-Call Status Bar is visible and invisible.

The problem I'm having is when this status bar changes, and the view has already been drawn it remains at it's current size. If the bar hides, the view is too small. If the bar appears, the view is too big and the top is hidden. If I use the navigation at the bottom to change to a new screen, everything is drawn correctly. The problem is only with the screen that is visible when the bar changes size.

Here are some images illustrating what is happening. This is what I see after a normal launch and then the bar is shown.

[image: Normal Launch]
[image: then the bar is shown]

And this is what I see when I launch with bar shown and then it is hidden.

[image: Launch with bar shown]
[image: then the bar is hidden]

What is the expectation to handle these scenarios correctly? Is there something in IB that should be selected but isn't, or do I have to do something programatically?

Comment: If you have found the solution please share I am facing the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I checked "full screen at launch" on my uiwindow in IB, and this resolved a similar issue.

Comment: Appreciate the idea, but that didn't change anything for me.